# Another way to say "be safe and come back soon"

Tags: phrases

I am looking into a specific expression I heard but could not remember it exactly. It means that be safe and come back soon, or any similar meaning. You say it to your friend/ relative when they leave.

I am sure it has this word: "victorious". Probably it is something like "return victorious". Also, it probably has the word "sail". It is NOT a common expression that you will hear everyday.

Comment: Smooth Sailing?

Comment: [Hasta la vista, baby!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasta_la_vista,_baby)

Comment: No, it has the word "victorious". Plus it is not that short -- otherwise I would have remembered it. It is more than 5 or 6 words.

Comment: "Come back safe and sound" is the most obvious one for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I remembered it.

Sally forth and do battle and return victorious.

I am not sure what its origin is or even whether it is any use?

Comment: It is a reference to a force of knights leaving a castle or fortified place under siege (a sally) and attacking the enclosing enemy.  Hardly means "be safe", though.

Comment: Great phrase! My dad would always shout out "SALLY FORTH" when ever we would go out anywhere.  It also happens to be the origin of the name of the [comic strip](http://kingfeatures.com/comics/comics-a-z/?id=Sally_Forth)

Answer (score 2):

Could you be thinking of ***shield*** rather than ***sail***?

[Return victorious with/on your shield](http://everything2.com/title/With+your+shield%252C+or+on+it)

> This was a common parting message given to the warriors of ancient
>   Sparta before they left for war. The soldiers in the phalanx were each
>   issued a large bronze shield, called a hoplon. Due to its size, if one
>   of them returned from battle without his shield it was suspected that
>   he had dropped it to flee the battle.
>
> If the soldier died valiantly in battle his comrades could use his
>   shield as a kind of litter to drag his body back to Sparta.
>
> Thus, the meaning of the saying is clear. The only acceptable options
>   are:
>
> ```
> Return victorious (with your shield)
> Return dead (on your shield)
> ```

Comment: Personally I wouldn't say this to a friend or relative unless I was being ironic, but it fits the OP's request.

Comment: Me neither, but s/he did say it wasn't common.

Comment: That hardly means "be safe"...

Answer (score 0):

These are called parting phrases.  The only one I have heard with the word "victory" is "Take care, victory lies ahead.", but it doesn't mention you are expected to return soon.

Answer (score -1):

Godspeed would have a similar connotation.